# Issues in upgrading ML libraries using AWS Sagemaker Notebook's Lifecycle configurations

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-machine-learning

I use the following script to automate upgrading of my libraries.

**My script (Start Notebook):**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo 'Before:'
echo $PATH

export PATH=/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/bin:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:$PATH

echo 'After:'
echo $PATH

echo `pwd`

source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate tensorflow_p36

pip install pandas --upgrade

pip install tensorflow-gpu --upgrade
```

**Error:**

I get the following error, how can I point to the correct location(/home/ec2-user) of keras instead of ***/root***

```
cp: cannot stat ‘/root/.keras/keras_tensorflow.json’: No such file or directory
```

**Full Logs:**

```
Before:
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
After:
/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/JupyterSystemEnv/bin:/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/4.8.5:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/usr/local/mpi/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
/home/ec2-user
cp: cannot stat ‘/root/.keras/keras_tensorflow.json’: No such file or directory
```

**Without lifecycle configuration:**

All the commands in the above script works.

Actual keras.json file is exising, under /home/ec2-user when I remove the lifecycle configuration with the following value.

```
sh-4.2$ cat .keras/keras.json
{
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like `pip install` in your case executed "outside" of virtualenv

try to change from:

`source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate tensorflow_p36`

to:

`source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate tensorflow_p36 && pip install pandas tensorflow-gpu --upgrade`

and delete redundant lines